# Handling comma-separated values with each value having its own commas Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, http

I am building a simple API in Spring Boot that accepts a query list of countries and binds them automatically to a List or Array of String.

The problem is, given

```
countries=Korea, Republic Of, Japan...
```

My array would be parsed as ["Korea", "Republic Of", "Japan"], instead of ["Korea, Republic Of", "Japan"]

I tried having an input of

```
countries=Korea%5C%2C%20Republic of, Japan
```

but it is still parsed ["Korea", "Republic Of", "Japan"]

Is there a way to properly handle those kinds of input?

I have an object

```
{
    String[] countries;
    /// other fields
}
```

and a REST endpoint of

```
@GetMapping("/exists")
public String getQuery(QueryForm Form form,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: No because , is the delimiter. How would you know that Republic Of and Japan is the same country?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli that doesn't answer the question. I am asking if there is a way to handle those kind of inputs, because whether I use an encoded comma, it is still parsed into separate values

Comment: no because you have comas weather they are url encoded or not